# Fluent Ribbon Backstage opening?

Tags: ribbon, fluent, ribbon-control, fluent-ribbon

is it possible in Fluent Ribbon to open programmmatically the Backstage control?

Answer (score 0):

Resoved setting IsOpen property of Backstage

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //execute the command from the View Model
  ((Fluent.Button)sender).Command.Execute(null);

  //close the backstage
  this.Menu.IsOpen = false;
}
```